# XML parsing of attributes using R

Tags: xml, r, parsing, attributes

I've been trying to get into R and thought the best way is to come up with a project that I like and dig into it. So I wanted to analyze my texting habits. I managed to export my texts as an XML file in the following format:

```
<all>
    <message date="1423813836987" number="+15555555" type="1" read="1" locked="1" seen="1">content of text</message>
    <message date="1423813836987" number="+15555555" type="1" read="1" locked="1" seen="1">another content of text</message>
</all>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to extract the attributes "date" and "number" and the content of each message and create a data frame. My end-goal is to create a graph for each "number" and see how often I text that number.

After looking around, I found the [XML package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) for R. I can extract the content of the message, but have not been able to get the attributes from the single `message` tag. Everything I found regarding attributes talked about nested tags like:

```
<message>
    <date>1423813836987</date>
    <number>555-555</number>
</message>
```

Would anybody point me to the right direction? Are there better way to do something like this? What I have so far is this:

```
doc = xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("~/Desktop/data.xml"))
xml_data <- xmlToList(doc)
```

But it makes the attributes look funky.

[image: How the data looks like in RStudio]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an option using `xpathSApply`:

```
## create an xml Doc, replace the text by your file name
xx <- htmlParse('
<all>
    <message date="1423813836987" number="+15555555" type="1" read="1" locked="1" seen="1">content of text</message>
    <message date="1423813836987" number="+15555555" type="1" read="1" locked="1" seen="1">another content of text</message>
</all>',asText=T)
## parsing 
data.frame(
  date=xpathSApply(xx,'//all/message',xmlGetAttr,'date'),
  number=xpathSApply(xx,'//all/message',xmlGetAttr,'number'),
  message=xpathSApply(xx,'//all/message',xmlValue))

##           date    number                 message
## 1 1423813836987 +15555555         content of text
## 2 1423813836987 +15555555 another content of text
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a little more succinctly using the Hadleyverse:

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

# I modified the second record to ensure it was obvious the values carried through

doc <- read_xml('<all>
    <message date="1423813836987" number="+15555555" type="1" read="1" locked="1" seen="1">content of text</message>
    <message date="1010191919191" number="+22828282" type="2" read="3" locked="0" seen="1">another content of text</message>
</all>')

msgs <- xml_find_all(doc, "//message")

bind_cols(bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(msgs), as.list)),
          data_frame(message=xml_text(msgs)))

## Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
## 
##            date    number  type  read locked  seen                 message
##           (chr)     (chr) (chr) (chr)  (chr) (chr)                   (chr)
## 1 1423813836987 +15555555     1     1      1     1         content of text
## 2 1010191919191 +22828282     2     3      0     1 another content of text
```

If you don't want to use `dplyr`:

```
cbind.data.frame(do.call(rbind, xml_attrs(msgs)),
                 messages=xml_text(msgs),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

##            date    number type read locked seen                messages
## 1 1423813836987 +15555555    1    1      1    1         content of text
## 2 1010191919191 +22828282    2    3      0    1 another content of text
```

It's also pretty easy to do it with the `XML` package, too:

```
bind_cols(bind_rows(lapply(xpathApply(doc, "//message", xmlAttrs), as.list)),
          data_frame(message=xpathSApply(doc, "//message", xmlValue)))
```

Lather. Rinse. Repeat base example if you want to stick with base.

If there are unneeded columns just use data frame column slicing to get rid of them.

If you want automatic type conversion you can take a look at `type.convert` but the `number` field is going to be problematic if you need the `+`.